# Bootstrap 4 table using whole screen

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make my page take up the entire width of the page, as per my client's requirement.    I tried to do the following.  The left side of the table is 10px from the left edge, but there's still a ton of whitespace to the right of the table.

```
<div class="container"  style="margin: 10px" >
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-striped">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`container` can have a maximum width of `1140px`. If you want `full-width` table, use `container-fluid` instead of the `container` class.

## https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvXYPp

---

`Container` is a block element. It is aligned in the center of its parent with the code below.

```css
.container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

`style="margin: 10px"` override the code above. Hence, the container is not any more in the center: it is on the left side of its parent.

---

To fix the issue, add the style directly for the table. The `table` does not have `margin-left` and `margin-right`, but it has `margin-bottom:1rem`. And that is up to you whether you override it or not.

```css
.m-10px {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-sm table-striped m-10px">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col ">#</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
          <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

## https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GdVOwV

Comment: That centers the table again, but still has a ton of whitespace on either side.

Comment: Thanks!  Going to container-fluid is making it do exactly what I'm wanting.